# collection_select and has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models - Contacts and Organizations - setup in a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
end
```

In the contact's new view, I have the following collection_select:

```
<%= collection_select('contact', 'organization_ids', @organizations, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => :true, :name => 'contact[organization_ids][]'}) %>
```

This works, but seems overly complicated for creating a multi-select box for this relationship.

Is there a better helper available for this particular relationship? I'd prefer to use a multi-select box - not checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "contact[organization_ids][]", organization.id, @contact.organizations.include?(organization) %>
```

Comment: Hey @Jatin - I appreciate the answer but check boxes aren't an option for this specific project.